# Find : $\lim_{n \to \infty} \{(\frac{n}{n+1})^\alpha+\sin(\frac{1}{n})\})^n$...

Tags: calculus, limits

Find : $\lim_{n \to \infty} \{(\frac{n}{n+1})^{\alpha}+\sin(\frac{1}{n})\})^n$

If I convert $n \to \infty $ to $ h \to 0$ where $h =\frac{1}{n}$

Therefore the given problem becomes $\lim_{h \to 0} \{(\frac{1}{h+1})^{\alpha}+\sin({h})\})^{\frac{1}{h}}$

$$
\begin{align}
\Rightarrow & \lim_{h \to 0} \left\{\left(\frac{1}{1+h}\right)^\alpha+ h \frac{\sin h}{h}\right\}^{\frac{1}{h}} \\
\Rightarrow & \lim_{h \to 0} (1+h)^{\frac{1}{h}}=e
\end{align}
$$

[ Using $\lim_{n \to 0} (1+a)^{\frac{1}{n}} =e $]

But the answer is $e^{1-\alpha}$ please suggest the mistake thanks.

Comment: what is $\alpha$ here?

Comment: You need to expand $(1+h)^{-\alpha}$ to the first order too.

Answer (score 3):

Let us consider $$A=\frac{1}{(1+h)^{\alpha}}+\sin({h})$$ and use Taylor series; as a result $$A=1+(1-\alpha) h+\frac{1}{2} \left(\alpha^2+\alpha \right) h^2+O\left(h^3\right)$$ So $$\log(A)=(1-\alpha ) h+\left(\frac{3 \alpha }{2}-\frac{1}{2}\right) h^2+O\left(h^3\right)$$ $$\frac{1}{h}\log(A)=(1-\alpha ) +\left(\frac{3 \alpha }{2}-\frac{1}{2}\right) h+O\left(h^2\right)$$

I am sure that you can take from here.